# In oracle SQL, how would you obtain the timestamp representing the start of the week?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle9i

I'm using an Oracle 9i database and want to obtain, within a function, the timestamp representing the start of the week, i.e. The most recent monday, at 00:00:00.

I am aware that the timestamp representing the start of the current day is `TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: You want the next monday, or the monday of the current week?

Comment: The monday of the current week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `next_day` to get that:

```
SQL> select next_day(sysdate-7, 'MONDAY') FROM DUAL;

NEXT_DAY
---------
29-APR-13
```

Comment: Thank you, so I want:
SQL> select to_timestamp(next_day(sysdate-7, 'MONDAY')) FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

Getting the start of the week should work with `trunc` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions242.htm#i1002084)).

So,

```
select to_timestamp(trunc(sysdate, 'D')) from dual
```

should work.

However, depending on your NLS settings, the first day of the week for oracle may well be Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

this appears to return Monday before the day of week in question at midnight.  to prove out just play around with sysdate and subtract days...

```
select case when to_Char(sysdate,'d') = 1 then
 trunc(sysdate-6)
else 
  trunc(sysdate - (to_Char(sysdate,'d')-2))
END
  from dual;
```

Comment: to_char(sysdate, 'd') - 2 looks like it should throw an exception.

Comment: @danbracuk it didn't for me.  I ran it against an 11g environment didn't have a 9 available.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate a date to Monday with:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'IW') FROM DUAL;
```