# select records weekly from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to select recods from oracle table for the current calendar week based on a date datatype field. Currently I am doing like this:

```
select * from my_table where enter_date > sysdate -7
```

If today is Thursday, this query will select records seven days from today which infiltrates to last week on Thursday. Is there a way to select records for the current calendar week dynamically?

Comment: If I am getting you then is it like Monday to Thursday as today is Thursday?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289302/in-oracle-sql-how-would-you-obtain-the-timestamp-representing-the-start-of-the/16289402#16289402)

Comment: Yes Roms That is is I need to select Only the records for the current Calendar week.

Comment: Rambling that question there is about the Next day. I am asking about The current weeek.

Comment: @Stanley, that post answers how to get the starting date of the week.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man I need the Whole weekk not the Starting day :P

Comment: @Stanley now check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_char(sysdate, 'd')` returns day of week in [1..7] range; so try using

```
select *
  from my_table
 where enter_date >= trunc(sysdate) - to_char(sysdate, 'd') + 1
```

Comment: Sorry I am a complete beginner on sql is this the same as `select * from  church_income_expense where TRAN_DATE>= trunc(sysdate, 'ww')`?

Comment: No. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084 "WW - Same day of the week as the first day of the year
 "; so trunc(sysdate, 'ww') will return nearest Tuesday since Jan 1st 2013 was Tuesday...

Comment: Ok Thank you Sir I apprciate.

Comment: This method has the feature (I won't say advantage or disadvantage, it's just "a thing") that it is sensitive to the NLS_TERRITORY. If the first day of the week is Sunday in a given country then this method will reflect that, not Monday.

Answer (score 2):

If your week starts on a Monday then:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  dates >= trunc(sysdate,'IW')
```

For alternative definitions of the first day of the week, trunc(sysdate,'W') truncates to the day of the week with which the current month began, and trunc(sysdate,'WW') truncates to the day of the week with which the current year began.

See other available truncations here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions255.htm#i1002084

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91031/4)**

**Below is the query which you can try**

```
select Table1.* 
  from Table1 
 where dates > sysdate - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')
```

Comment: Sorry, but you have to truncate the sysdatein order to eliminate time component from the date one: imaging, that sysdate is '15.08.2013 19:50:15.123'.